# MySQL SELECT record immediately prior to range and select range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table of states for three things, a,b and c

```
id  a   b   c   time
--------------------------
1   0   1   1   78
2   1   1   0   89
3   1   0   0   105
4   0   0   0   107
5   1   0   1   122
6   0   0   1   134
7   0   1   0   167
8   1   1   1   168
9   0   1   0   177
10  0   0   0   180
```

As an example, the bounds of time are chosen by the user as time>100
AND time<170

But I need to know the value of ‘a’ immediately prior to the 1st returned record. (where id=2)

I’m trying to find the most efficient way of creating this query, without resorting to 2 separate queries.

```
SELECT  a, time FROM states WHERE time<100 order by time DESC limit 1
AND
SELECT  a, time FROM states WHERE time>100 AND time<170 ORDER BY time ASC
```

To return a result set of ...

```
a   time
1   89
1   105
0   107
1   122
0   134
0   167
0   168
```

Any advice would be gratefully received, thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please explain why your desired result set doesnt include time 168, when this is less than 170?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post to clarify/correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses `LEAD()`:

```
SELECT  a, time
FROM (SELECT s.*, LEAD(time) OVER (ORDER BY time) as next_time
      FROM states s
     ) s
WHERE next_time > 100 AND time < 170;
```

You can also use:

```
select s.*
from states s
where s.time >= (select s2.time from states s2 where s2.time <= 100 order by s2.time desc limit 1) and
      s.time < 170;
```

This, alas, doesn't work when the subquery returns no values.  That can be fixed, but it complicates the query.

However, your solution is actually fine (with `union all`):

```
(SELECT  a, time
 FROM states
 WHERE time <= 100 
 ORDER BY time DESC 
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT  a, time
 FROM states
 WHERE time > 100 AND time < 170
)
ORDER BY time ASC;
```

From a performance perspective, this should be okay if you have an index on `time`.  This also readily handles the problem when there are no values 100 or less.

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . I'm not going to speculate on the database being used.  Thank you for pointing out the typos.

Comment: Point 1 was more for the OP, in case he was wondering why it wasn't working out.. And you're most welcome sir!

Comment: Many thanks Gordon, that is just what I needed - UNION ALL - I appreciate your help!